# Compare two dates in Codeigniter and MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

How can I get values between two dates in Codeigniter query function? Here is my model and sample code.

```
function get_promo() {
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT FROM tbl_event WHERE event_id = $id AND event_startdate <= $today
    AND event_enddate >= $today');
    return $query;
}
```

But it doesn't work, here is the error I got

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tbl_event WHERE event_id = 36 AND event_startdate <= 2011-06-09 ' at line 1

SELECT FROM tbl_event WHERE event_id = 36 AND event_startdate <= 2011-06-09 AND event_enddate >= 2011-06-09

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need qoutes around your date (i.e. '2011-06-08'). try this

```
function get_promo() {
    $today = date('Y-m-d');  
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT FROM tbl_event WHERE event_id = {$id} AND event_startdate <= '{$today}'
        AND event_enddate >= '{$today}'");
    return $query;
}
```

If your columns `event_startdate` and `event_enddate` are `DATETIME` type but you are only interested in the date part you can do `DATE(event_enddate) to extract the date part

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->where('date_start <=',date('Y-m-d'));
$this->db->where('date_end >=',date('Y-m-d'));
$query = $this->db->get('table');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u need to user date_format(), more information in this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format.

Try this code:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT FROM tbl_event WHERE event_id = $id AND DATE_FORMAT(event_startdate ,'%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT($today ,'%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(event_enddate ,'%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT($today ,'%Y-%m-%d')");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried it but I didn't get result.. . I do have a event_start 2011-06-09 and even_enddate 2011-06-30 but it doesn't show

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with your queries because they are not correctly escaped. To fix this, try adding single or double quotes.
You can also consider using [Query Binding](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) or [Active Record](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data), both simple and secure methods for handling queries. @danneth answer may be helpful in this regard.
Here are some examples of how to use binding and [Active Record](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) based on your code.

**Query Binding Example**

```
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql = 'SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  tbl_event 
WHERE event_id = ? 
  AND event_startdate <= ? 
  AND event_enddate >= ?';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id, $today, $today));
return $query;
```

**Active Record Example**

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select('*')->from('tbl_event')
        ->where(array(
            'event_id' => $id,
            'event_startdate <= ' => $today,
            'event_enddate >= ' => $today
        ))
        ->get();
return $query;
```

Append `->result()` or `->result_array()` etc to get the result in an object or array. Look into the Codeigniter [Database User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the right format. Try this:

```
$todaystart = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');  
$todayend = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');  
       $query = $this->db->query('SELECT FROM tbl_event WHERE event_id = $id AND event_startdate <= ? AND event_enddate >= ?', array($todaystart, $todayend));
```

EDIT: your query is wrong. Do this:

```
$todaystart = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');  
$todayend = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');  
       $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_event WHERE event_id = $id AND event_startdate <= ? AND event_enddate >= ?', array($todaystart, $todayend));
```

Comment: It's now working but I didn't get any query i do have on my database event_start 2011-06-09 and even_enddate 2011-06-30 but it doesn't show