# Codeigniter Date comparison - Greater than or Less than datetime field not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I have the following queries in codeigniter to find any data in which the datetime field is more than 24 hours. Here is my try...

```
$this->db->where('date_reg >', 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)');
```

But the above query is not working!

What I want in short is, return all rows which the date_reg is more than 24 hours...

I can not use query in codeigniter!
Here is the format for `date_reg` field....2019-02-19 08:00:00

How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates in Codeigniter and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288261/compare-two-dates-in-codeigniter-and-mysql)

Comment: it is not duplicate, my field is datetime type. that is big different

Comment: What your format of date in 'date_reg' can you add a format

Comment: Here is the format....2019-02-19 08:00:00

Comment: Hope you can do that as `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));` ?

Comment: @MR.Internet did my answer help you?

Comment: Not really, I am working round...but still no luck...

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for an older record that was recorded within 24 hours of the current date?
Because let's take today's date. 2019-02-21.

```
$this->db->where('date_reg >', 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)');
```

This query is essentially saying Find records greater than the current date. So it will look for records between `2019-02-21` and `2019-02-22`, which might return empty.

Try this instead. I try to analyze the question as much as possible, rather than throw an half-assed answer

```
$this->db->where('date_reg <=', 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('your_table');
$this->db->where('date_reg >=', '(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)', false);
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: not working, the issue might be my date_reg field type is datetime, is that might be the problem?

Comment: I have tested it. SELECT * FROM `customer_entity` WHERE created_at >= (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
Its working on my side for my customer column.

Comment: I also have datetime thats not a problem you can do one more thing let me share

Comment: $this->db->where('DATE(date_reg)', '>=', '(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)');

Comment: apply DATE() function on your field which will compare date .. try it if it works then will check for hour as well

Comment: this isn't working at all ... the first parameter is the key the second the value and the third is a bool whether you want to escape it or not (default is `true`) - take a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#CI_DB_query_builder::where a proper solution would be `$this->db->where('date_reg >=', '(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date_reg >= now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;');
```

Comment: I can not use query, because I have a lot of other info. It should be as codeigniter style...

Comment: Okay, try.
$this->db->where('date_reg >=', 'NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY');

Comment: $this->db->where('date_reg >=', DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)');

Comment: Can you try the last one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188809/discussion-between-dodis-and-mr-internet).